# google map not working when i deploy the app in android device but not via play store

Tags: android, dictionary

I have developed an app that uses google map v2. when i tried to import the package in my android device using export signed application in eclipse. the map is not working.

Comment: Whats the error you are getting. Did you add the API key in your manifest file, that could be one reason if you see a blank screen

Answer (score 0):

When you configure Google Maps SDK, you have many different keys : your key corresponding to your debug.keystore with is the keystore when you run the app from your IDE, and your release.keystore (the name you specified when your create a new one) which is the certificate you sign the app with when you build your apk.

The last key seems not been added to your project : https://console.developers.google.com

Check to official [documentation about this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#display_your_apps_certificate_information%20section) and also *Displaying the release certificate fingerprint* on the same page

Lastly, don't forget to change the google maps key in your manifest before building the apk